# Auto Browser Refresh of Ring-Server with Boot

Tags: clojure, ring, boot-clj

I would like my browser to refresh automatically when I change my ring handler (I'm using Hiccup to generate my html). I'm using the `:reload` option of `serve` from boot-http which works fine, but I always have to manually refresh the browser.

Leiningen seems to have an auto-refresh? option, but I couldn't find something similar for boot. There's also [ring-refresh](https://github.com/weavejester/ring-refresh), but that's really old and seems incompatible with the latest version of Clojure.

Is there a simple way for boot to refresh the browser after my code changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with Ring-Refresh was an outdated dependency on Compojure. Adding the latest version of Compojure as a dependency solves the problem.